# AG Grid SSRM Tree Data - prevent visual state reset on column sort/filtering events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using React AG Grid v30 and my grid is configured to with `rowModelType: "serverSide"` and `treeData: true`. Here is a portion of my AG setup:

```
type AgGridServerSideGetRowsCall = {
  readonly groupKeys: string[];
  readonly sortColumn?: string;
  readonly sortDirection?: AGGridSortDirection;
  readonly success: (params: LoadSuccessParams) => void;
};

function App() {
  const [currentServerSideGridGetRowCall, setCurrentServerSideGridGetRowCall] = useState<AgGridServerSideGetRowsCall>();

  // Imagine code here that consumes currentServerSideGridGetRowCall 
  // to then make a fetch call to retrieve rowData for the SSRM Tree 
  // Data grid and eventually calls the success handle

  const gridOptions = useMemo(() => ({
    rowModelType: "serverSide",
    treeData: true,
    // ...other stuff
  }), [])

  return (
    <AgGrid
      {...gridOptions}
      onGridReady={(e) => {
        e.api.setServerSideDatasource({
          getRows({ request, success }) {
            const sortRequest = request.sortModel[0] ?? {};

            setCurrentServerSideGridGetRowCall({
              groupKeys: request.groupKeys.slice(-1),
              sortColumn: sortRequest.colId,
              sortDirection: sortRequest.sort,
              success: success.bind(this),
            });
          },
        });
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

The question I have is related to behavior I am observing in my app with this setup. When I expand groups in my tree data grid, my server side datasource receives a `getRows` request as you would expect and I then proceed to fetch the data and then eventually invoke the `success` handler to populate the data for that request. I can do this as many times as I need for all the groups I expand and it all works. One thing to note about each of these group expand requests is that the `groupKeys` that are sent as part of the `request` object from `getRows` are populated with the information signifying which tree group was expanded.

Now, the problem I am concerned with arises when I attempt to trigger either column sorting or filtering AFTER having expanded a number of tree data group rows. What happens in that event is that I end up receiving a `getRows` request for the grid with the filter/sort model set properly, but the `groupKeys` I receive in that request are empty `[]` which implies the request is not for an "expanded" group. It is basically a root-level request.

The question I have is, how do you maintain the SSRM Tree Data expanded rows state when triggering a column sort/filter event in this scenario? That request I receive with `groupKeys = []` is akin to making the initial grid data request for the root level rows but with a column sort/filter model applied.

Is the expectation such that I have to locally maintain which groups are expanded and *manually* expand the table groups via imperative calls to the Grid api interface? (i.e. find the nodes that should be expanded and do `node.setExpanded(true)` to force the SSRM grid to re-request those rows with the proper column sort/filter)